# Why is NGINX is ignoring my query strings?

Tags: nginx, query-string, php

I recently switched from APACHE to NGINX. However, somewhere along the way NGINX started ignoring my query strings. For example, I use pagination like so:

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=5
```

This simply loads `example.com` as if the query string wasn't there.

Here's the configuration (**edited as suggested by Nelson**):

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default:**

```
server {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/www/;
        index   index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        # Pass PHP scripts to PHP-FPM
        location ~ \.php {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        client_max_body_size 8M;
}
```

Comment: Editing the question such that the part that was the problem (see accepted answer) is not in there anymore? Seriously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use this as Location :

```
location ~ \.php {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

To be more specific your following two lines are removing the query string:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated the file and restarted `php5-fpm` and `nginx` but the problem persists...

Comment: You may have some rewrite rule in place, post the full file, replacing  site names or other personal data.

Comment: It seems the culprit is "location ~ \.php?$ {" do use the version I wrote on my answer, which is "location ~ \.php {"

Comment: Yes, I tried your version first but it still wasn't working, so I tried adding that back in just for the heck of it. Neither seems to work...not sure what's going on here...

Comment: check the content of /etc/nginx/conf.d/ and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ for files that could be causing this.

Comment: Just checked - conf.d is empty and sites-enabled just has default (same as sites-available)

Comment: are you restarting nginx "/etc/init.d/nginx restart" after your changes? you must do so..

Comment: How does setting the SCRIPT_FILENAME fastcgi_param remove the query string? I am seeing similar issues, but require this parameter.

Answer (score 48):

I was having the same problem. I changed the location section in my nginx virtual host file as below and it works fine for me.

```
location / {
   # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had is_args missing and this fixed my issue where query strings were being ignored.