# GET attribute are ignore while requesting data from WooCommerce REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I have a CRM set to *crm.example.com* And a active store on *example.com* (on the same server)
Both running with NGINX.

Im trying to request the whole categories list (43 categories) but i'm getting only 10. (The default value set by WooCommerce).

I tried using the per_page parameter but it seems like the server is ignore the GET.

I checked the request sent from *crm.example.com* and got that:

```
object(Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request)#85 (5) {
  ["url":"Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request":private]=>
  string(67) "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories/?per_page=100"
  ["method":"Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request":private]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["parameters":"Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["per_page"]=>
    int(100)
  }
  ["headers":"Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Accept"]=>
    string(16) "application/json"
    ["User-Agent"]=>
    string(32) "WooCommerce API Client-PHP/1.3.0"
  }
  ["body":"Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request":private]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

But yet there is only 10 results.

i'm thinking maybe the NGINX server is ignoring the GET parameters as a security policy?

Comment: Im using nginx with standard setup, it's getting me crazy because the same code is working just fine while the store and the Backend are on Apache

Comment: After hours of research [I Found my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654521/why-is-nginx-is-ignoring-my-query-strings)